# Responsive chart growing uncontrollably

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-chartjs

I have a vue component that implements vue-chartjs's HorizontalBar component that I render as a cell in a bootstrap-vue table. My desire is to have the chart maintain a fixed height but scale horizontally as the window grows/shrinks.

The chart plays nicely enough when the page is first loaded but grows uncontrollably on re-size to cover other elements on the page.

[image: Mostly working at the start, though the graphs aren't quite filling the space]
[image: Once I resize the screen, the graphs take over]

How do I make them properly responsive without them going where they shouldn't? I'd also like to make sure they actually take up the extent of the table cell they're in, rather than weirdly stopping a few pixels short.

Here's my relevant component code:

```
<script>
import { HorizontalBar } from "vue-chartjs";
import Constants from "../../services/Constants";

export default {
  name: "ResponseGraph",
  extends: HorizontalBar,
  props: { /* some props */ },
  data: () => ({
    chartData: {},
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{ stacked: true, display: false }],
        yAxes: [{ stacked: true, display: false }]
      },
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      tooltips: {
        enabled: false
      }
    }
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.chartData = {
      datasets: [
        // some data
      ]
    };
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
};
</script>
```

And how I'm using it inside of my table code:

```
      <template v-slot:cell(graph)="data">
        <response-graph
          :correct="data.item.correct"
          :incorrect="data.item.incorrect"
          :omitted="data.item.omitted"
          :height="20"
        />
      </template>
```

Comment: Have you tried to give response-graph a width ? I don't have much experience with vue, but I work with chart js on daily basis, chances are you will have to set witch to canvas element of chart js full width and housing element a width for it to function properly.

Comment: Will that fix its width though? I don't have a specific number that the width should be, it just needs to fit to the container it's in

Comment: Just tried it, didn't fix the issue

Comment: try to go with percent value and try different sizes, most likely you will find the sweet spot.

Comment: Give extra padding to that tr element? I actually have a exact setup like that in a table, try the padding if it does not work, let me know, i will check and revert you back.

Comment: The component can't take a percentage value for the height or width props. The base component is explicitly coded to take number values for them. Is there some sort of wrapper I might need to put around my component?

Comment: Since you are using just a simple horizontal bar chart, why not switch to something simple like the  `<b-progress>` component, which is very lightweight, and expands to fit its parent's available width.  https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/progress#multiple-bars

Comment: That didn't even occur to me. Probably makes the most sense too because it's already in my project (so no new dependencies). I'd still love to figure out why the chart.js solution isn't working, but at the end of the day my client doesn't care which one it is, just that it looks right.

Thanks for all the work you do on Bootstrap-Vue by the way!

Comment: I have sent you msg on the chat, check if the height thing makes it work.

Comment: The answer to why chartjs is not resizing is to be found in [this note](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/responsive.html#important-note)  under the `responsiveness` chart configuration option. Wrap the chart in a div with `position:relative` only containing the chart and it will resize correctly.

Comment: please provide a codepen example